# Colour histogram based on value from secondary column for exploratory analysis

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-visualization, visualization

I'm looking at some employee attrition data where we have a binary 'yes' or 'no' output. For my exploratory analysis I have used

`df.hist(figsize=(16,20), bins=50,xlabelsize=8, ylabelsize=8)`

to give me a histogram of each value and its count

I would like to compare the yes' to no's on top of each other, probably by overlaying two histograms by the **Attrition** column so i can understand which features are important or by colouring values by this (akin to a stacked bar chart).

With the count of rows on y axis

Comment: Can you include your `df` in your question so we can copy and paste it?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/pavansubhasht/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset

I took the dataset from this kaggle link

Comment: [Seaborn's catplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with its many variations looks like a good place to start exploring.